# Sticking Injector or dead CIS?

Tags: vw, fuel-injection

I have an VW 83 gti (mostly stock except for MSD system) that is having some troubles starting. Basically, when the engine is cold, it starts like a dream. I was previously having some very rough idle issues so I had my CIS system tuned, now it runs like a dream.

However, I have one small problem (which has been around for sometime now), when I drive her for more than 25+ minutes and then turn off the engine - I am SOL, the engine will not start when hot. It cranks but never "catches" that is then paired with the obvious wall of gas fumes. I then have to leave it for 3+ hours before I can start it again, although push starting it works every time.

The guy I bought it from told me he thought that the injector on cylinder 2 was sticking, but I am not sure, I brought it to a shop and they are talking about replacing the whole CIS if they can find one.

Any suggestions for troubleshooting it or list of things to check for?

Thanks for helping me save some cash,
John

Comment: Please define SOL

Comment: Ah, I see :) I don't have experience with continuous injection vehicles but have a book handy that highlights the likely culprits. Will post up an answer shortly

Comment: One question, do you know if your CIS is K-Lambda or KE?

Comment: @Kaid, K-Lambda

Comment: @Paulster2 the cold-start injector is different from the actual fuel injectors in this setup. If it is stuck open in a hot engine the AFR can become too rich for combustion to occur. I believe this is what is happening here, because the OP says that the car runs great otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Don't be hasty to replace the whole CIS!

Based on the Bosch Fuel Injection & Engine Management book, here are a few things to investigate as possible causes for hot-start issues (inability to start when the engine is warm):

1. ***Cold-start valve leaking or operating continuously***

   The cold-start injector is designed to enrich the air-fuel mixture while the engine is cold by adding more fuel. This is supposed to be inactive when the engine is warm and is operated by the thermo-switch (or thermo time-switch).

   If the valve is leaking or kept open by a faulty thermo-switch then this can explain why the engine refuses to run and results in the smell of petrol vapor.

   Based on the information provided in the question, **this would be my top suspect**.
2. ***Insufficient residual fuel pressure***

   This covers several possibilities like leaky fuel injectors, fuel leaks in the fuel lines, faulty fuel pump check valve or faulty fuel pump accumulator.

   There are tests for determining which part could be at fault, but those should really have separate questions of their own.

---

There are a few other possibilities mentioned, but I'd first investigate 1 and 2 before considering them:

3. ***Air-flow sensor plate rest position incorrect***
4. ***Lambda control faulty***

Comment: Just an update, the CSV is operating continuously. I ended up taking a look at the hot start relay and the thing was completely rusted out. I removed it from the fuse box and now it starts like a dream. I am going to start looking into a new relay. Once I replace that I will see if I am all set - if not I will inspect the thermo switch

Answer (score 1):

Had same problem.  The issue rests with the Thermo Time Sw.
When cold the thermo time sw. completes the ground for the cold start valve to shoot extra fuel into the manifold.  When hot the Thermo Time switch opens the ground and does not allow this to occur. Yours, apparently is not opening the ground and the cold start valve is spraying fuel in when hot, in which case the engine floods and will not start.  To test, when hot remove the electrical connector to the Therm Time Sw. and try starting. Should be ok.  The hot start relay provides a delayed intermittent spray from the cold start valve when engine hot and cranks more than 2-3 seconds.

Comment: This is correct. Also, with the new relay, I can hear it "click" which is it engaging the valve.